# How to run a published npm package

Tags: node.js, npm

I just published my first npm package.

Let's say the name of the package is auditor-connector. While developing the package, I was running it as npm start, and running the index.js file in it with certain arguments as follows.

```
npm run start arg1 arg2
```

I do know how to **use** this package in another project by *install*ing it, and *require*'ing it.

However, is there a way, I can enable anyone to just **run** this package as a tool. Think of it as a tool I would like anyone to run, instead of a library, that I would like someone to use in code. I would expect something like the following `npm run <name-of-package> <arg1> <arg2>`since you would also have to specify the name of the package with the arguments it expects.

Answer (score 0):

There's `npx`, the npm package manager. When you run

`npx <name-of-package> <arg1> <arg2>`,

`npx` checks `node_modules` for the  executable. If it's not there, `npx` downloads the package from `npm` and then executes it.

Comment: I created a project, installed my npm package, and ran with the same arguments I run. I get this error.
npx: installed 49 in 11.918s
command not found: sizeauditor-connector

Comment: Did you publish the module to npm?